# Change callback function variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to change a page variable using the NYT Article Search API, so I can go to the next 10 results. I've got the page number as a variable I just need to either change it using another function or reload the query when I click the link for the next page or previous page.

```js
function articleSearch() {
  $('nav').hide();
  var pageCount = 0;
  var search = $('#search').val();

  $('#articles').submit(function(evt) {
    $('#searchHead').remove();
    evt.preventDefault();
    // var search = $('#search').val();
    var fromAlt = $('#fromAlt').val();
    var toAlt = $('#toAlt').val();
    var sort = $('#sort').val();
    var formData = $('#articles').serialize();
    formData = encodeURI(formData);
    var url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
    url += '?' + $.param({
      'api-key': "API-KEY-GOES-HERE",
      'q': '"' + search + '"',
      'begin_date': fromAlt,
      'end_date': toAlt,
      'sort': sort,
      'fl': "headline, byline, pub_date, snippet, web_url",
      'page': pageCount
    });
    $.getJSON(url, displayResults);
  }); // end article submit func
}

function displayResults(dataFromServer) {
  $('#searchHead').remove();
  $('#resultsList').remove();
  $('#articleHeader').remove();

  var results = dataFromServer.response.docs;
  var metaTag = dataFromServer.response.meta;  
  if (metaTag.hits < 10) {
    $('nav').hide();
  } else {
    $('nav').show();
  }

  $('#articles').after('<h2 id="searchHead"></h2>');
  $('nav').after('<ol id="resultsList"></ol>');
  $('nav').after('<p id="articleHeader">Viewing articles ' + ' of ' + metaTag.hits);
  var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
  var toDate = $('#toDate').val();
  var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
  var searchString = "You searched for " + searchTerm + " from " + fromDate + " to " + toDate;

  $('nav').append('<h2 id="searchHead">' + searchString + '</h2>');

  $.each(results, function(resultsIndex, resultsValue) {
    var headline = resultsValue.headline.main;
    var byline = resultsValue.byline.original;
    var pubDate = resultsValue.pub_date.slice(0, 10);
    var snippet = resultsValue.snippet;
    var link = resultsValue.web_url;
    var article = "<a href='" + link + "'>" + headline + "</a> " + byline + '<br>' + pubDate + "<br>" + snippet;
    var li = '<li>' + article + '</li>';
    $('#resultsList').append(li);
  }); //end each func
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking; you want to change `pageCount` on each successful submit?

Comment: Yes. I want to update it so I can show the next 10 results

Comment: You need to either make it outside the scope of `articleSearch` and update it in `displayResults`, or create a `displayResults` function generator that takes it as a parameter and modifies it in the generated function.

Comment: So I've got it outside the scope and I can update the count when I click on the next link, how do I get it to reload the query with the next 10 results?

Comment: Same way you do it now?

Comment: Thanks! I just copied and pasted the code from the submit anon function. It works.